# gtk_menu_item_new_with_labelex vs gtk_menu_item_new_with_label

Tags: c, gtk, gtk2

what is the difference between these two function calls:

```
menu_item_new_with_labelex  vs gtk_menu_item_new_with_label
```

Answer (score 2):

gtk_menu_item_new_with_label() is a standard gtk constructor that creates a GtkMenuItem containing a GtkAccelLabel with the specified text.

gtk_menu_item_new_with_labelex() is not a standard function; it does not exist in any of the gtk header files; in fact, google has never heard of it. If you see it in your code, it's probably some sort of a wrapper created by another person in your team.